# Datanode in slave isn't working : Hadoop

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos

I've created a hadoop cluster between two machines using by following the link!

http://tecadmin.net/set-up-hadoop-multi-node-cluster-on-centos-6/

The problem that we face is, let's take two systems hadoop1 and hadoop2.

hadoop1 is the master as well as slave and hadoop2 is slave.

when we start the services using bin/start-all.sh, all services including datanode for hadoop2 is initialing.

but when I check the DFS size, using bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report. only 1 system i.e hadoop1 is detected. I've check all possible things..

when I start the service, everything is well.

I've checked jps in the hadoop1 as well as hadoop2. In hadoop1, all services are displayed, whereas in hadoop2, only jps is running. so which means, data node in slave isn't working.. whereas in master it is showing datanode is starting on hadoop2 as well.. When I checked the logs, there is no such logs for hadoop2 slave.

I've tried all possibles explanations including the namespaceID which we get from namename current VERSION and assign it to data node current VERSION.

What could be the solution for this? I use centOS 7, and apache hadoop 1.2.1

Comment: Im going to shoot at the dark, if your dfsadmin is empty, you should check the ports,example: `:8031`(hadoop2 version, check it on docs which port is on hadoop1 version) which is resourcemanager. Or you didn't configure the `hdfs-site.xml` correctly

Comment: Or you can try this question as follow up, but I was using hadoop2. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529409/hadoop-datanode-slave-is-not-connecting-to-my-master`

Comment: hdfs-site.xml is configured exactly how it is given in that link,

and the link you've sent,it is for hadoop with YARN. I've used hadoop 1.2.1 stable version. 

Still no queue.